# Connecting Google Container Registry to Cloud SQL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

we're using Google App Engine and Cloud SQL for a django web app. We want to run migrations during the build; however, GAE uses Container Registry to build the app, and Container Registry not authenticated to access Cloud SQL. So, as expected, the migrations fail to due to a rejected connection.

How does someone authorize Container Registry to access Cloud SQL?

Answer (score 1):

When you say:

> GAE uses Container Registry to build the app, and Container Registry not authenticated to access Cloud SQL.

I assume that you mean:

> GAE uses Container Builder to build the app, and the Container Builder Service Account is not authenticated to access Cloud SQL.

Assuming that's what you need, this document explains how to use IAM to grant additional permissions to the Service Account: https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/how-to/service-account-permissions

If you are in fact asking a different question, please clarify, including an example that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for the answer. The documentation is a little confusing. It says that the API will automatically create a service account - it didn't. However, we already have a `<project ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com` service account handling deployments, which has the permission, `Owner`, which is suboptimal, but we're getting permission denied errors with other roles.  This service account, despite having project wide ownership permissions, is denied access to Cloud SQL. Is the Cloud Builder service account required?

Comment: Actually, David, I did find the service account and managed to change the permissions to add `Cloud SQL Client` but I'm still getting the same connection denied error

Comment: I would expect Cloud SQL Client to be sufficient. Please confirm that you added this to your Cloud Builder Service Account which is named <project_number>@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com in the IAM console here: https://pantheon.corp.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project If that is indeed all correct, the only other suggestions I have are (1) temporarily adding me as a viewer on your project so I can confirm and (2) contacting Cloud SQL to see if they can help. For #1, our contact e-mail address is gcr-contact@google.com, include a link to this question in your e-mail.

Comment: Thanks David - really appreciate the availability. We solved this by changing the permission from Cloud SQL Client to Project Editor